# Is it possible to take data from one web-page and generate another (webpage to be printed) without any interference of server?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to take data from a HTML `<form>` and generate a report from that data for printing, as the internet connection is not persistent, it is important report in print format is generated on client side only i.e. a web-browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate BOTH the screen and print versions from the server at the same time.  Enclose different parts in DIVs with class="NotOnPrint" for the screen-only stuff, class="NotOnScreen" for the print-only stuff, and nothing extra for items that should appear on both screen and print.  Then use this CSS:

@media screen { .NotOnScreen { display: none; } }
  @media print  { .NotOnPrint  { display: none; } }

Answer (score 1):

It is if the page with data supports CORS

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing

Otherwise you hit the browser security limitations.

If you do not control the page providing data it probably won't work.

Answer (score 0):

If the data in the original HTML is sufficiently regular that you can parse it with reliability, it is possible to write a browser-resident [bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) that will mangle the DOM in any way you choose; if you packed enough logic into the bookmarklet, you could even delete the original, keep the data, and create a completely new page with the data, rendering from templates.

This is not, however, your basic Javascript app.  Bookmarklets are something of a Dark Art.

Comment: sounds awesome, thanks a lot :) Can i have some tips or pointers in order to learn this **Dark Art** ?

Comment: How to make a Bookmarklet: http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-make-a-bookmarklet-for-your-web-application/  The "dark art" bit is in learning how to cram the entire thing, library and all, into a single string that'll fit in a browser's bookmarks file.